# Chrome XMLHttpRequest POST encoding issue

Tags: google-chrome, xmlhttprequest, fileapi

I send file with XMLHttpRequest, like this:

```
self.xhr.open("POST", params.url + "?al=" + params.accessLevel + "&desc=" + params.desc + "&album_id=" + params.aid);

var boundary = "xxxxxxxxx";
self.xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "multipart/form-data, boundary="+boundary);
self.xhr.setRequestHeader("Cache-Control", "no-cache");
self.xhr.setRequestHeader("X-Requested-With", "ajx");

var body = "--" + boundary + "\r\n";
body += "Content-Disposition: form-data; name='"+(params.fieldName || 'file')+"'; filename='" + encodeURIComponent(params.file.name) + "'\r\n";
body += "Content-Type: application/octet-stream\r\n\r\n";
body += self.reader.result + "\r\n";
body += "--" + boundary + "--";

if(self.xhr.sendAsBinary) {
    // firefox
    //self.xhr.overrideMimeType("application/octet-stream; charset=utf-8");
    self.xhr.sendAsBinary(body);
} else {
    // chrome (W3C spec.)
    self.xhr.send(body);
}
```

In Firefox it works perfectly. Take a look a the firebug screenshot: http://s8.postimage.org/4dw4gd5j7/Untitled.png

However in Chrome it looks terrible: http://s8.postimage.org/h7yrng8cl/chrome.png

Looks like an encoding issue. I tried to add a `charset` utf-8, but it still didn't work.

Comment: Is your problem that the data is getting set incorrectly or that the debugger text is getting muddled?  The latter looks to be a browser bug.

Answer (score 0):

different browser handle different. would you try jquery $.ajax . javascript library like jquery, YUI is supposed to iron browser difference.